# PostgreSQL - Limit user to connect only to replica (and not to the master node)

Tags: postgresql, rds, postgresql-9.6

Is it possible to limit a user (in this case a read only one) to be able to connect just to a read replica instance and not the main one?

(i know a firewall is an option, i am just wondering if there is something with PostgreSQL i can do instead)

Comment: I think you should just create a readonly user on master

Answer (score 1):

You should configure [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) on the servers so that the user is rejected on the server where you don't want a connection, and allowed on the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the input. problem is that i am running on AWS RDS and don't have access to pg_hba. thanks!

Comment: And they don't give you a way to configure which hosts can connect and which ones not? Something like a firewall?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue - AWS RDS - whether it's possible or not? To restrict access only to Read-replica. in MS SQL world we do the following: Primary -> Replica, create user on Primary -> user replicated to Replica; disable user on Master. Now we have user on Replica only. Is it possible to do on Postgres?